# Pug.js - Passing in pug files to use from JS

Tags: javascript, templates, pug

I've got a `Main.pug` file that I'm using as a container for multiple other `.pug` files I want to include in it. However the set of other files isn't static, ie `Main.pug` could include `A.pug` or it could include `B.pug`. Which file to use would be passed in from express similar to the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('main', {section:"A.pug"}) 
})
```

I've tried a few ways to do this in Main.pug including the following:

`include #{section}`

and it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have advice or tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('main', {section:"A"}) 
})
```

Inside `main.pug`

```
-if (section == 'A')
    include A.pug
-else if(section == 'B')
    include B.pug
```

Hope it helps.